# Как разделить логику unit тестирования?

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, junit, robolectric

На текущий момент в `Application` имею следующий фрагмент кода:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;


        sAppComponent = buildComponent();
        sAppComponent.inject(this);

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
            Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
            //todo for unit tests
//            Timber.plant(new UnitTestTree());
        } else {
            Timber.plant(new CrashReportingTree());
        }
    }
```

Во время юнит тестирования возникает конфликт между `Stetho` и `robolectic`, но даже если бы его не было стетхо в юнит тестировании мне не нужен. Но нужен `UnitTestTree()` для вывода некоторой информации в консоль (`System.out.println()`). И каждый раз при юнит тестировании выношу в коммент одну строку и разкомменчиваю другую, а при обыкновенной работе наоборот.

Собственно вопрос - есть ли какой то способ во время работы `Application` компонента нативно выяснить - это юнит тестирование или нет.

Comment: что именно вы хотите тут протестировать?

Comment: тут - ничего и не требуется тестировать. Не понимаю смысла вопроса

Comment: юнит-тест - это тест выполняемый в изоляции. т.е. он не должен зависеть от других классов. покажите класс который вы хотите тестировать.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman я не понимаю, зачем вы спрашиваете и говорите очевидные вещи? Есть проблема и требуется ее решить, для чего вам дополнительные данные?

Comment: я подозреваю, что у вас XY-проблема и поэтому задаю дополнительные вопросы.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman хорошо. Есть unittest на, допустим бд. В методах класса который мы тестируем у меня ведется логирование. Во время выполнения теста мне так же хотелось бы иметь в консоли выполнения теста, где отображаются результаты, видеть то что я логирую. Но возникла проблема то что стандартый Log.d (в моем случае Timber.i()) не выводит эти данные. Для такого случая я создал свой Timber.tree который выводит данные в консоль (банально System.out.println) который работает. Так вот мне бы хотелось что бы при unittest это Tree инициализировалось, в обратном случае - не инициализировалось

Comment: вы должны тестировать отдельно основную функциональные требования (поведение объекта) и отдельно не функциональные (логирование, производительность и т.п). это будет два совершенно отдельных теста. unit-тесты не должны (по возможности) трогать БД - это замедляет тесты и не приносить какой-то выгоды.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman очень полезное замечание. Однако он ни как не связан с вопросом